# How to call a js function on a remote host?

Tags: javascript

how to write a program/script that will click a button on a web page? The button's function is:`OnClick="func();"`. Firebug gives no information about the called function, so I can't call an AJAX query.

:)

Comment: Can you give a bit (a lot) more information about what you're trying to do?!

Comment: The server can't call the client- yet the client can call the server - you can use local events / user event to trigger server functions and methods that in turn can change the Clint state. However, the client starts the communication.

Answer (score 1):

There is [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click) method for Input and Anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with JavaScript, without dumping the contents of the page on your page or using an iframe. And, you can't interact with elements inside `iframes` from outside of it (unless it is on the same domain; thanks @Pekka)

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks :) You learn something new everyday.

Comment: this is a good article on the issue:  https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: I knew about the same-origin policy, but didn't know that it applied to `iframes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that unless you control the server of web page to some extent (in which case you can use cross-domain AJAX or something equivalent), but you might be able to replicate the effect of clicking the button. This is known as a [CSRF attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have button A. When button A is pressed, function X is supposed to run. You could use the click method as DoubleThink suggested, or you could just directly run function X.

option 1 = `document.getElementById('A').click()`

option 2 = `X()`

Note: many people suggest doing this: `document.getElementById('A').onclick()`, but there are multiple ways to bind functions to events and this way does not cover all those ways -- it only covers the case where someone had `<button onclick="..."/>`. For Example, if you use jQuery, using `.onclick` will not suffice.